# Deleting a line of text on an NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a NSTextView called `TheTextView`. I'm adding there lines of text, each line representing a full path to a file with a `\n` at the end. The textview is set to `not editable`. I add or remove text via a `+` and `-` buttons.

Supposedly the user can select a line and delete it. I've tried with

```
[TheTextView delete:nil];
```

But nothing happens. How can I delete the selected line? And while we are in this topic, is there any way to set the TextView to select the whole line when I click on one line?

Thanks

EDIT:

OK, so I found that if I do the following

```
[TheTextView setEditable:YES]; 
[TheTextView delete:nil]; 
[TheTextView setEditable:NO];
```

then it works. Now I need to know how to select the entire line when the user click it because otherwise it will leave a blank space in between the two lines where the one deleted was. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like no text is selected when you call `[TheTextView delete:nil]`.  Try calling `setSelectedRange:` with a range to select a line of text, then try calling `delete:`.  For example:

```
[TheTextView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0,24)];
[TheTextView delete:nil];
```

Of course, you'll need to determine the correct start and length of your range to correspond the text you want to delete.

Comment: thanks. how do I call setSelectedRange? Sorry but I am a complete newbie to Obj-C. I'm a C programmer.

Comment: I tried with the following: `NSRange range = [TheTextView selectedRange]; [TheTextView setSelectedRange:range]; [TheTextView delete:nil];` but it didn't work.

Comment: I've been trying to figure how to do that (determine the correct start and length) but I have no idea since I don't even know how to get the selected text and do a simple strlen().

Comment: `NSRange range = [TheTextView selectedRange]; [TheTextView setSelectedRange:range];` doesn't accomplish anything - it gets the range that is currently selected...and then selects it.  `NSRange range = [TheTextView selectedRange]; NSLog(@"%d", range.length)` will write the length of the selected range to your console.

Comment: I passed `range.length` to `setSelectedRange` as: `[TheTextView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0,range.length)];` then called `delete` and all it does it move the selection to the first line. I really don't understand what you want me to do.

Comment: Apparently this is failing because `editable` is set to false on the NSTexView. The how come I am able to add text (via a range) to the textView?

Comment: OK, so if I do the following `[TheTextView  setEditable:YES] [TheTextView  delete:nil]; [TheTextView  setEditable:NO];` then it works. Now I need to know how to select the entire line when the user click it because otherwise it will leave a blank space in between the two lines where the one deleted was. Ideas?